# jQuery Add css and remove it after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hy guys, I would like to know how remove css styles after click event,

In fact at the first click I add css and remove some other things but I would like at the second click get the same css code at the beginning.

```
$('#show').click(function (){
  $('.sub-menu').css('width', '185px');
  $('.sub-menu').css('-webkit-transform', 'none');
  $('.sub-menu').css('transform', 'none');

  // and second click 

  $('.sub-menu').css('width', '');
  $('.sub-menu').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(0)');
  $('.sub-menu').css('transform', 'scale(0)');

})
```

I don't want use `toggleclass` method cuz I don't want touch the css file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple option is to keep some kind of boolean marker.

```js
var applied = false;

$('#show').click(function() {

  if (!applied) {
  
    $('.sub-menu').css('width', '185px');
    $('.sub-menu').css('-webkit-transform', 'none');
    $('.sub-menu').css('transform', 'none');
    applied = true;

  } else { // and second click 

    $('.sub-menu').css('width', '');
    $('.sub-menu').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(0)');
    $('.sub-menu').css('transform', 'scale(0)');
    applied = false;
    
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you don't want to touch the css file. How about you create a css rule using jQuery and append it to the `head` tag.

```
var rule = $('<style>.myclass{width:185px; -webkit-transform:none; transform:none;}</style>');

$('html > head').append(rule);

$('#show').on('click',function(){
    $('.sub-menu').toggleClass('myclass');
});
```